# Attempt to read property "nom" on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am facing this error 'Attempt to read property "nom" on null' in Laravel 10. though the User eloquent model work fine beside for Plaques;

Here is my Code:

Plaques Model:

```
class Plaques extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'Plaques';

    protected $fillable = ['nom', 'zone', 'el_plaque', 'tranche', 'gc_mecanise', 'gc_trad', 'gpon', 'ville', 'status_plaque', 'closed_by' , 'created_by'];

    public function chambres()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Chambres::class);
    }

    public function immeuble()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Immeuble::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Chambres Model:

```
class Chambres extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'Chambres';

    protected $fillable = ['ref_chambre', 'type_chambre', 'chambre_terminer', 'loc_x_chambre', 'loc_y_chambre', 'plaque_id', 'user_id', 'status_chambre', 'created_by', 'closed_by', 'affected_by'];

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photos::class);
    }

    public function immeuble()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Immeuble::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function plaques()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Plaques::class);
    }

}
```

ChambresController:

```
use App\Models\Chambres;
use App\Models\Plaques;
use App\Models\User;

class ChambresController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.chambres.index')
        ->with('chambres', Chambres::get());
    }
```

View:

```
<tbody>
            @forelse ($chambres as $chambre)
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"><a href= "/admin/chambres/{{ $chambre->id }}" class="badge badge-primary" role="button">{{ $chambre ->ref_chambre }} </a></th>
                <th scope="col">{{ $chambre->type}}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ $chambre->plaques->nom}}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ $chambre->user->name}}</th>
                <th scope="col"><a href= "/admin/chambres/{{ $chambre->id }}/edit" class="badge badge-primary" role="button"> Modifier </a></th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <form id="valider" action="/admin/chambres/{{ $chambre->id }}" method="post" class="hidden">
                    @csrf
                    @method('delete')
                    <button class="btn" role="button">Supprimer</button>
                </form>
                </th>
            </tr>
```

Chambres Migration:

```
        Schema::create('chambres', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('plaque_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('ref_chambre')->unique();
            $table->string('type_chambre');
            $table->date('chambre_terminer')->nullable()->change();
            $table->string('loc_x_chambre');
            $table->string('loc_y_chambre');
            $table->boolean('status_chambre')->nullable();
            $table->string('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('closed_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('affected_by')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('plaque_id')->references('id')->on('plaques')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

i want to get 'nom' column value from 'Plaques' table which has foreign key on 'Chambres' table.

Comment: Error message seems quite clear. The variable is null, likely because there are no matching records in the database. Check before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $chambre->plaques is null, you can not get the nom property. You can consider to fix it like below:

```
<th scope="col">{{ $chambre->plaques ? $chambre->plaques->nom : ''}}</th>
<th scope="col">{{ $chambre->user ? $chambre->user->name : ''}}</th>
```

Try pass 'plaque_id' as the second parameter

```
 public function plaques()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo(Plaques::class, 'plaque_id');
 }
```

Or change your model Plaques to Plaque

Comment: the thing is it is not empty and when i did that it work but it doesn't return the value from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can querying `plaques` like below in your controller to fix the empty data load issue:

```
$chambres = Chambres::with('plaques')->get();
```

Change view code like below to display empty string if `plaques` return null value.

```
<th scope="col">{{ $chambre->plaques ? $chambre->plaques->nom : '' }}</th>
```